# Qual a diferença entre Serviço e Software de Aplicação?

Tags: services, application-service, software

Sempre me questionei sobre a diferença entre os termos `serviço` e `software de aplicação`. Ambos possuem significados parecidos, mas qual a grande diferença em si? Segue abaixo algumas definições sobre os termos.

> *Os serviços do Microsoft Windows, antes conhecidos como serviços NT,
>   permitem que você crie aplicativos executáveis de longa execução em
>   suas próprias sessões do Windows. Esses serviços podem ser
>   automaticamente iniciados quando o computador inicializa, podem ser
>   pausados e reiniciados, e não apresentam nenhuma interface de usuário.
>   Esses recursos tornam a serviços ideais para serem usados em um
>   servidor ou sempre que você precisar da funcionalidade longa execução
>   que não interfere em outros usuários que estão trabalhando no mesmo
>   computador.*

Fonte: [Serviços Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Software aplicativo (aplicativo ou aplicação) é um programa de
>   computador que tem por objetivo ajudar o seu usuário a desempenhar uma
>   tarefa específica, em geral ligada a processamento de dados. Sua
>   natureza é diferente de outros tipos de software, como sistemas
>   operacionais e ferramentas a eles ligadas, jogos e outros softwares
>   lúdicos.*

Fonte: [Software de Aplicação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_aplicativo)

Answer (score 1):

Serviço: normalmente é um software que roda em segundo plano e realiza tarefas especificas, pode ou não ter algum tipo de interface seja via linha de comando ou gui. Um serviço não requer muita atenção do usuário.

No windows pelo menos a diferença entre um serviço e aplicativo/software/programa é a comunicação dele com o kernel.

Aplicativo: É um software que realiza uma tarefa especifica(edição de textos, executar um arquivo de audio), geralmente é chamado por demanda do usuário.